# curdate() query not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have one problem in my query is `CURDATE()` not working in my laravel 5.2

> AbsenController@index

```
$now = time();
$absen = Absen::with('siswa')->where('level', '=', 'Siswa', 'AND', 
'created_at', '<=', 'CURDATE()')->get();
return view('absen.index')->with('data', $absen);
```

and this is record in my Absen Table

[image: Absen Table]

Comment: `query not working` ... _what_ is not working?  Can you execute _any_ query from your Laravel code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with your `where` sytnax.  Try including separate terms for each of the two conditions in your `WHERE` clause:

```
$absen = Absen::with('siswa')
    ->where('level', '=', 'Siswa')
    ->where('created_at', '<=', DB::raw('curdate()'))
    ->get();
```

As a variant, you could also use `whereRaw()` to handle the condition involving `CURDATE()`:

```
$absen = Absen::with('siswa')
    ->where('level', '=', 'Siswa')
    ->whereRaw('created_at <= curdate()')
    ->get();
```

Conditions are ANDed together by default, which is the relationship you have between your two conditions.  Look into `orWhere()` if you want to OR together conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @AzzarioRazy You should elaborate on what `not works` actually means.  Maybe there is a problem with your connection.  Can you execute _any_ query from your Laravel code?  My answer is correct, or at least should be, assuming you have no other problems than what was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = time();
$absen = Absen::with('siswa')->where('level', 'Siswa')->where('created_at','<=',\Carbon\Carbon::now())->get();
return view('absen.index')->with('data', $absen);
```